# Convert Unix timestamp in PST to IST

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, timezone

I am trying to convert any Unix epoch time value into IST timezone.

Unix date:
`date -d@1509872957` gives `Sun Nov  5 01:09:17 PST 2017`

for UTC:
`date -d@1509872957 -u` gives `Sun Nov  5 09:09:17 UTC 2017`

Is there any similar way to convert for IST time-zone. I tried using command `TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date`, but I am not able to work it out for any epoch.

Comment: your epoch timestamps are saved in a file? if yes, you can add `-f epochfile` (also every timestamp should starts with `@....`) into your commamd to convert them all at once (I think this option should be GNU date specifc)

Answer (score 1):

For you as a user, you can update your view of the date/time with this command

```
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
```

If you have a time in seconds since the epoch you can either run the `export` command above or give the setting to `date` each time you use it

```
date --utc --date '@1509872957'                # Sun  5 Nov 09:09:17 UTC 2017
date --date '@1509872957'                      # Sun  5 Nov 09:09:17 GMT 2017 (my timezone)

TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date --date '@1509872957'    # Sun  5 Nov 14:39:17 IST 2017

export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
date --date '@1509872957'                      # Sun  5 Nov 14:39:17 IST 2017 (your timezone)
```

With sufficient rights you can update the system's view of the time, since it seems to be PST. On my Debian-based system it's `tzselect` for an interactive selection.